# How Can I Get This Simpler

Tags: java

So this is my code

The only issue I am having is make one part "simpler" but will do the same thing.

The part that I want to make simple is:

```
char[][] grid = new char[(message.length() == key.length()) ? 
message.length() : ((int) Math.ceil((float) message.length() / (float) 
key.length())) + (int)Math.ceil((float)(message.length() % 
key.length()) / (float)key.length())][key.length()];
```

I know that "?" means an if and ":" means else.

Any tips would help thanks.

Comment: By splitting it into multiple sentences? This thing is unreadable

Comment: this works in my code perfect and if the rest of the code helps i could post but this is only "issue" im having

Comment: Just because something works does not mean it is readable. Why do you have to use ternary operator? A normal if-else would be  much more readable.

Comment: in the java editor it was one long line but it doesnt allow to do that on the site.

Comment: What is `message` and `key`. Are they Strings?

Comment: this is horrible. split this up into multiple lines. The fact that it fits into one line in your IDE doesnt make it better.

Comment: This is either equal to 1 or 0: `(int)Math.ceil((float)(message.length() % 
key.length()) / (float)key.length())`

Comment: yes they are strings

Comment: i know that one line isnt the greatest that why im asking what i should do to fix it using if and else

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a more readable code.

```
int gridRow = (message.length() == key.length()) ?  message.length() : ((int) Math.ceil((float) message.length() / (float)  key.length())) + (int)Math.ceil((float)(message.length() %  key.length()) / (float)key.length()); 
char[][] grid = new char[gridRow][key.length()];
```

Comment: thanks for the help guys. im going to see what works and ill post here

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible thing you can do is make your code readable and use good naming convention split into various statement so it is readable.

Instead of ternary operator use if else statement